# How can I know the location from where I cloned my git repository

Tags: git

I have cloned the git repo from my servers to different folders. Now I am confused from where I had cloned few specific repositories from. How can I know the location I cloned the git projects from?

Comment: Try `git remote -v` and you'll probably see an 'origin' repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do use...

```
git remote -v
```

That should do the trick

Answer (score 6):

Using:

```
git remote show origin
```

or:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

Answer (score 3):

When you `git clone` a repository, Git automatically adds a *remote* named `origin` which refers to the place from which you cloned the repository.

```
git remote -v
```

will show you all of your remotes and their URLs.

If you have removed this remote, then you cannot tell from where the repo was cloned.

Answer (score 0):

You do:

```
vim REPO/.git/config
```

Or:

```
git remote show origin
```

Or:

```
git remote -v
```